# PRISM: Is there a way for a View to know which region it is being created for?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a view which is registered with several different regions in the application, each time with a call like

```
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(regionName, viewType);
```

It is then instantiated by Prism somehow when it's needed. Is it possible to determine in the view class constructor, which region the view is going to be injected into?

I am trying to reuse same view in several similar situations, where the visuals of the GUI would be same, but the view model behind the view would be instantiated differently, for example. I could expect this to be an architectural oddity, but I am rather constrained by the large-ish application's infrastructure. I can affect the code that registers the views, so if there is a way to pass along some metadata to accompany each registration, which could be later retrieved during instantiation, I could do that.

Comment: What you want is to negate the core benefit of having reusable views, which makes little sense. If you need to change the view (i.e. new behavior for new region), then your view isn't properly reusable. If different things are needed in different regions, then it's not the same view, is it?

Comment: Well, he has a reusable _view_, not reusable _view models_, and he wants to change only the _view model_ depending on the region.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for templating or viewmodel first. Instantiate the appropriate viewmodel. Template content into ui. You can do that in Prism, or you used to be able to do anyhow.  In my experience, the various intricacies of Prism often get in the way of things are otherwise quite simple without all it's regions and whatnot. However you do it though, you're best decoupling parent and content so neither has to rely on knowing what type each are.

Comment: Actually, reusability is the key idea here. I have several regions where the GUI is supposed to be similar and applied to different business situation in each case. So, same GUI, different behavior. It bugs me quite a bit that I had to have separate views only in order to have different VMs instantiated for me. Which is why I wanted to somehow take over the instantiation of VMs - either in the view where I get control or in a custom ContentLoader (which had its own complications). Still going with separate views in the end, but all of the meat is taken out into a user control, so - ok for now!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to determine in the view class constructor, which region the view is going to be injected into?

None that I know of with the default `RegionNavigationContentLoader`.

That being said, you're not forced to use the default implementation, and `IRegionNavigationContentLoader.CreateContent` receives the full `NavigationContent`, so you should be able to detect a "view model influencing region" as target and manually create the correct view model (instead of relying on the `ViewModelLocator`) for the view.

Alternatively, go view model first and put a correct view model in each region in the first place while they share the same view. Admittedly, this may be the larger change to your application, but probably cleaner.